# Simple but precise benchmark for GM

Tags: game-maker

I'd like to have a benchmark for testing my games. Tried this but It's not precise enough:

```
var t = delta_time;
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    show_debug_message(time_get_current() * t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting `math_set_epsilon`, as this may negatively affect result of the test. Making it real low should be enough to solve the case.